# change time format for a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a function to change the time format and an offset is used to shift the date

For example, I have a string

```
"this is a string 2012-04-12 23:55 with a 2013-09-12 timezone"
```

I want to change it to something like

```
"**this is a string 20-Apr-2012 13:40 with a 19-Sep-2013 timezone**"
```

That is, the format of the data change from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd-bbb-yyyy` and the date is shifted by offset.

I write the following function but it only gives "this is a string 20-Jun-2012 13:40 with a 2013-11-12 timezone"

```
import re
import time
import datetime

def _deIDReportDate(report, offset=654321):
    redate = re.compile(r"""([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+)|([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)""")
    match = redate.search(report)
    for match in redate.finditer(report):
        dt = match.group()
        if len(dt) > 10:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
            new_time = dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')
            newReport = report[:match.start()] + new_time + report[match.end():]
            return newReport
        else:
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
            dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
            new_time = dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
            newReport = report[:match.start()] + new_time + report[match.end():]
            return newReport
```

Can anyone help to fix/improve my code?

Comment: "but there is error" .....do you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: What's the error? What is the current result?

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: `report` is a string. It doesn't have the `groups` method, so `report.groups()` won't work.

Comment: How can I change it to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is caused by you trying to call `report.groups()`; you never applied the regular expression on the `report` parameter.

Your code can be simplified significantly:

```
_dt = re.compile(r"""
    [12]\d{3}-   # Year (1xxx or 2xxx),
    [0-1]\d-     # month (0x, 1x or 2x)
    [0-3]\d      # day (0x, 1x, 2x or 3x)
    (?:\s        # optional: time after a space
        [0-2]\d: # Hour (0x, 1x or 2x)
        [0-5]\d  # Minute (0x though to 5x)
    )?
    """, flags=re.VERBOSE)

def _deIDReportDate(report, offset=654321):
    def replace(match):
        dt = match.group()

        if len(dt) > 10:
            # with time
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
            return dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M')

        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
        dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
        return dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

    return _dt.sub(replace, report)
```

The `replace` nested function is called for each non-overlapping match in the input string.

Comment: Maybe should break out the regex with VERBOSE?

Comment: @AaronHall: Is in that long? I can break it up a bit perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you a question why you specify "10" in "if len(dt)>10?"

Comment: @neymar: the date portion is 10 characters long; 4 digits for the year, 2 for the month, 2 for the day, plus 2 dashes makes 10.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciated your kind help

Comment: Hi Martjin, sorry to bother you again. I tried to build my own code. However, it changes either one of the date instead of change them all. Can you help me with it? Thank you                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106969/change-time-format-for-a-string

Comment: My answer was updated since the version you used was written, but you seem to have missed how it changed. You are returning too early from your function; my version uses a helper function for `re.sub()` instead.